# Printing a simple double number in java

Tags: java, double

pls enlighten me why the heck is this not working ? :| it's just a simple output line , god i'm so frustated. I know it might be something very that i miss , but i can't figure it out.

```
double a = 155/124;
System.out.printf("%f\n", a);
```

it prints

```
1.00000
```

Comment: try double a = 155d/124d; instead

Comment: thx , i was sure it was just a small fry :)) , thx guys , and sorry for the duplicate

Comment: well it's quite often that new comers to java don't know this ... when you write a number it is *always* an integer and must be casted to whatever you need (eg. String str = ""+0; <-- integer or even if you write long l = 2147483648; <-- Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 won't work, because 2147483648 is again an integer!!)  [okok - it's not **always** an integer, but mostly always]

Answer (score 2):

it's working just fine. Just remember 2 things:

1. you're using integers, the result of the calculation will be an integer
2. rounding errors

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double a = 155d / 124d ;
System.out.printf("%f\n", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are dividing two ints without casting it to double explicitly. 
Add (double) cast to variable a:

double a = (double) 155/124;

Or, you can create one of the numbers to be double, like:

double a = 155/124.0;

Hope this helps.